# .htaccess - Need help working with it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So today I realised my VPS still had 3 domains pointing to the origin IP - I have never worked with Apache conf files and have just attempted to add my own .htaccess from my own research:

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.infamystudio.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.infamystudio.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This was placed into the var/www folder and has had no effect on rewriting other domains pointing to the origin back to my IP.

Is there any good tutorials or can anyone help me write a rewrite so I can stop this.

Comment: Open the `httpd.conf` and see what code base the other deployments are pointing to.

Comment: @chris85 I am not sure what you mean - I have no clue working with this!

Comment: The requesting domain name is mapped to a code base. You need to make sure the `.htaccess` is in the location the domain is pointing to, otherwise you'll never hit the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file should be in the root folder of your website, but it will only be used by Apache if the Virtualhost configuration allow a override. So because I don't know what kind of VPS you have you have to find it yourself.
In Debian like servers this is usual in `/etc/apache2/site-enable/<virtual-host>.conf` (all files in site-enable are only links to the the files in the folder site-available)

Allowing rewrite for your VirtualHost

```
<Directory "/var/www/path/to/public">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

If this step is missing, nothing in your .htaccess file will work. If you have already a Directory-Direktive just only add `AllowOverride All` You may want to restrict this later but just for testing **ALL** would be good.

You also can have multiple Virtual host configurations for different IP or domain names.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: I have gone into the config settings of httpd.conf and set it to be enabled - now this all works! My question is I am unsure now how to block a rewrite from a domain accessing my origin?

Comment: Sorry I do not get your question. Can you give us a example what you try to block.